# Understanding explicit cast for String producing different results in c# and Java

Tags: c#, java

I wrote a same(..similar?) piece of code for Java 7 and C#(.net 3.5) and got a confusing output. Please help me in understanding this behavior:

Java:

```
public class strTest {
    public static void main(String [] s) {      
        String s1 = "abc";
        String s2 = new String(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'});
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);                      // false
        System.out.println(((Object)s1) == ((Object)s2));  // false
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));                 // true
    }
}
```

Output : false
false
true

C#:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String s1 = "abc";
            String s2 = new String(new Char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'});
            Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);                     // true
            Console.WriteLine(((Object)s1) == ((Object)s2)); // false
            Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2));                // true
        }
    }
}
```

Output : True
False
True

I am aware of concepts like String immutability and String pool but I guess I am missing the finer print.

In java: Why did it create a new String object for s2 when it could have used the one which is referenced by s1? Isn't that what String pool is supposed to achieve?

Comment: Please read the formatting help for future questions, and use the preview to see what your question is going to look like before posting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two aspects to your question: when objects are created, and how `==` comparisons work:

**Object creation**

In terms of interning ("pooling") - only *constants* are interned automatically. You can intern other strings using `Intern`/`intern`, but when you just call the string constructor that will *always* create a new string. (Well, except for one bizarre corner case in .NET, but we can ignore that for now.)

So in your code, `s1` and `s2` always refer to different objects.

**Comparison**

The cause of the difference is your use of `==`. C# supports user-defined operator overloading, and `String` overloads it like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(string x, string y)
```

which compares the contents of the string rather than the references. So when you have two operands of type `string`, `x == y` ends up doing an equality comparison rather than an identity comparison. That's why the first line of the C# output is `True`.

Java *doesn't* have this behaviour, which is why is prints `false`.

When the operand types are `Object`, both C# and Java will use reference equality, which is why the second line is false in both cases.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does C# have a `===` operator to fall back to the standard meaning of `==`, or is the casting to Object the only way?

Comment: @JBNizet: There is always the static `object.ReferenceEquals(object a, object b);`. Makes the intent clearer than casting in my opinion.

Comment: @JBNizet: No, there's no such operator - as linac says, just call `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the answer. just out of curiosity, is the corner case -> new String(new char[0])?

Comment: @PankajKohli: Yes, that's the one. It's bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking why C# says that s1==s2? String comparison compares the contents of two strings in a case sensitive manner. Since both strings have the same contents, their comparison returns true.

In Java only the string references are compared, to determine if the two variables refer to the same string. Their contents are not compared.

As for pooling, both Java and C# use pooling (interning in C#) for literals. Strings created programmatically result in new instances in both languages, even if a pooled instance already exist. Check the documantation of [String.Intern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) for an example similar to yours, where the interned string is a different instance from the generated string even if their values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

String pooling is used only with literals.
If you say String s1 = "abc"; String s2 = "abc"; there will be just one object created.

Comment: Not sure it's really in the question context but +1 for making me discover this in Java.

Comment: @Michael thanks, it's just at the end of the post. He asked why are there two objects for s1 and s2.

Answer (score 0):

The java language specification requires that when you use the 'new' keyword an actual new object is created, no cheating and returning an internal cached copy.

[A new class instance is explicitly created when evaluation of a class instance creation expression (§15.9) causes a class to be instantiated.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Interning is applied to strings expressed as literals, but when you explicitly use the new key word, the language has to make you an actual new, different, object.